# Query the last n,15 topics from a message board with a parent child relation

Tags: mysql, join, parent-child, last-modified

I've changed my database design from a separated topic/post table one to a single one with parent child relations.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `channel_id` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `parent_id` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `author` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `bbcodes_enabled` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `state` int(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `article_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `author` (`author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `message` (`message`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=401614 ;
```

Now I want to create a topic list. If the parent_id equals 0 the line represents a new topic. Else the parent_id contains the id of the root element.

This question is in some things similar to my other one but I thought new schema new question...

If someone submits a new post for a topic the date of the new post is the last_activity_date for the topic.

What I want is to find all topics ( limit x,offset  ) and order them by the last_activity_date which can be found in the last submitted post for the parent element.

The topics are linked to a channel which is equal to a category in a normal message board.

Mostly it should look like this BUT.. ordered by the date of the last post.

```
SELECT p.id, p.date, p.author, p.title, p.state, a.name, a.avatar, a.color 
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN authors a
ON a.id = p.author
AND p.channel_id = 126
AND p.parent_id = 0
ORDER BY p.id 
DESC
```

I'm not that bad in understanding mysql. But I have totally no clue how to do this. I had this situation several times and until now never found a solution. Only workarounds like using two or three queries..

I hope, and I really hope.. someone can help me with this situation.

My temporary solution for this here is a 3 query one (not acceptable) like:

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id 
FROM posts 
WHERE channel_id = x 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Loop over the results and run these two queries:

Query 2:

```
SELECT date as last_ativity from posts where parent_id = x DESC LIMIT 1
```

Query 3:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = x
```

Wanted Results ( on the website ) looks like this:

```
1. TopicTitle | last activity 1 second ago
2. TopicTitle | last activity 35 seconds ago
3. TopicTitle | last activity 1 min ago
4. ...
...
```

Comment: To clarify, because I may not be reading thoroughly enough, is there only _one level_ of parent/child relationships, or do you need to recurse up several levels to 0?

Comment: Yes. No recursive listings. And this is just to get the topics in correct order. Not the posts for it. Like: topic1 -> last changed: 1min ago, topic2 -> last changed 3 mins ago...

Comment: And are you intending to return details about the last posted author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding the problem to solve, you can do it by performing a `LEFT JOIN` against a subquery returning the most recent `date` per `parent_id`.  A `LEFT JOIN` is used in case a topic has *no* posts associated, and therefore no most recent activity.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.author,
  p.title,
  /* other fields from posts to related to the topic...*/
  /* Choose the joined date if non-null, otherwise the topic parent date */
  COALESCE(d.last_activity_date, p.date) AS last_activity_date,
FROM
  posts p
  LEFT JOIN (
    /* return latest date per parent_id */
    SELECT parent_id, MAX(date) AS last_activity_date
    FROM posts
    GROUP BY parent_id
    /* and join back to the main posts table */
  ) d ON p.id = d.parent_id
/* Only get the top-level threads */
WHERE 
  p.parent_id = 0
  AND p.channel_id = <value>
ORDER BY last_activity_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 15
```

Formatting the date to look like *"35 seconds ago"* is best done in your application code, rather than in the SQL query, and many languages have libraries specifically for generating "human readable" times of that sort.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'd.last_date' in 'field list'. But this looks good. Fixed it: d.last_activity_date

Comment: Sorry, I had a different alias in the subquery vs the select list.

Comment: On the first look it seems to do what I want. Just let me validate it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I have to run and will be away for about 2hrs, but will get back to you if you have questions.

Comment: ok. if there are no posts except the root post ( topic ) it returns null values. But that's something I can figure out on my own. Thanks for this. It does what I asked for and is all i need. Thanks.

Comment: Just one question. Where do I have to add the limit x,15? Within the subquery or outside?

Comment: The limit goes on the outside. I also forgot a where clause to only select parent 0 for the outside query

Comment: I see it now..^^ But as said. I can fix this.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem if i add 'WHERE channel_id = 146'. It ignores the channel_id.

Comment: The `chanel_id` should be checked in the outer query's `WHERE` clause, not in the join condition. I added logic to get the non-null date, plus the appropriate `WHERE` clause above.

Comment: You're stuff rocks. http://abload.de/img/bwerkoes8l.jpg +1 As far as I can see everything works. I will use permutations of this query on several parts of my project. So yes. Big thanks. I wouldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: Hi Michael. I discovered that the pagination doesn't work. Since max() selects always the top valeus without caring about the offset. What would you suggest? Splitting this query in two smaller ones or try to figure out how to make it work?^^

Comment: @user2429266 What exactly is your goal? The subquery as I have it above has no `WHERE` clause of its own, and will get the most recent post for each topic regardless of the limit. What do you expect the limit to have in connection to the `MAX()`? What precisely do you want to limit?

Comment: sry. it was my fault. I changed something and didn't remember it.

Comment: @user2429266 Ok, glad it's not more complicated.